# Tkinter create_window, justify to center

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this piece of code and I want these buttons to be at center of line. Unfortunately justify doesn't work and `text.window_config(INSERT, align="center")` gives me error like this: `no embedded window at index "insert"` I know there is problem with INSERT but I have no idea what else should I put there.

```
#text.window_config(INSERT, align="center")
for page in range(number_of_pages):
    page = page+1
    button = Button(text, text=page)
    button.configure(command=lambda button=button: goTo(page))
    text.window_create(INSERT, window=button)
```

Comment: Show us a minimal example please.What's the `window_create()`?AFAIK, only `tkinter.Canvas` has a function called `create_window()`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA: the text widget allows you to embed windows too.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am just point out the typo(maybe) in his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the window at the insertion cursor causes the insertion cursor to move one to the right. To reference the newly created window you can use "insert-1c", meaning "insert cursor minus one character" since a window logically takes up one "character" of space.